# Server IP address showing in Google SERPs suddenly?

Tags: url, dns

In the past week or so I'm seeing pages of my site showing up in Google results like this 204.232.210.182/cartoon/0615/ instead of like this www.andertoons.com/cartoon/0615/.

Any idea what might have caused this? Is this something I should be worried about?

Also, just in case I'm asking this incorrectly, please be gentle. It's my first time asking a question here.

Thanks! :)

Comment: This sounds like a server configuration situation, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

yea you probably dont want the ip showing.  Comment is right its more of a server configuration issue than programming, but in any case I found this article with a quick google search and thought it might be helpful

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=206c67522cc3946f&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Probably someone who was scraping web content, pointed a URL at your website homepage using the IP address. Then Google's crawler indexed your site using the IP address as the root of the URL. Not much that you can do about it other than configuring your web server to only accept HTTP 1.1 and higher requests containing the full domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Then Google's crawler indexed your site using the IP address as the root of the URL. Not much that you can do about it other than configuring your web server to only accept HTTP 1.1 and higher requests containing the full domain name

https://www.myminifactory.com/stories/real-fortinet-certified-professional-nse4-fgt-7-2-questions-to-kill-your-exam-stress-65793d31bdaef